# Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'

Tags: mysql

I created a Google Cloud sql database, and I tried to access it with DataGrip.  However, I get this message when I try to create a table:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'
```

Answer (score 0):

Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema':

```
1.) Check username and password.
2.) Check user access permission.
```

Comment: Create another user to simulate the problem then use that new user created.

Answer (score 0):

Check your conection information or try creating a new username and password.

In other cases can be the host..

Regards!